# Como aumentar una valor en un array de sesion en PHP?

Tags: php, sesiones

soy nuevo en este tema de php... estoy intentando aumentar una variable $cantidad de una sesion "carrito" ya creada para un carrito de compras.
la idea es, una vez mostrado el producto poder aumentar o disminuir la cantidad del mismo y a su vez aumentar el precio... pero no logro modificar su valor
capturo el evento click con JS pero al momento de aumentar la variable de sesion "cantidad" no la aumenta, lo he intentado de varias maneras pero no logro conseguirlo

```
foreach($_SESSION["carrito"] as $indice =>$arreglo){
       
        
            $precio[$indice]=$arreglo["precio"];
            $cantidad[$indice]=$arreglo["cantidad"];
             echo'
             <div id="producto" class="producto" method="post">
                <div  class ="imagen"><img src="'.$arreglo["imagen"].'" heigth=70 width=70></div>
                <div class="descripcion">'.$arreglo["producto"].'</div>
                <div class="talla">'.$arreglo["talla"].'</div>
                <div class="cantidad"> 
                <a class="name-cantidad">Cant.:</a>
                    
                    <div class="restar"><a>-</a></div>
                    <label class="cantidad-producto" id="cantidad-producto'.$indice.'"> <a>'.$arreglo["cantidad"].'</a></label>
                    <div class="sumar"><a id="sumar'.$indice.'">+</a></div>
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="precio">
                <label class="name-precio">Precio:</label>
                <a>'.number_format($arreglo["precio"],2).'</a></div>
                
                <div class="eliminar-producto"><a href="Mycar.php?item='.$indice.'">X</a></div>
            </div>
            
            <script>
                  
                 var addProduct = document.getElementById("sumar'.$indice.'");
                 addProduct.addEventListener("click",function(){
                 var cant=1;
                 alert("click en producto numero: '.$indice.'");
                 console.log("cantidad : '.$arreglo["cantidad"].'");
                 
                    
                 ';
                
                $_SESSION["carrito"][$indice]["cantidad"] =$arreglo["cantidad"]+1;
       
             echo'console.log("cantidad es: '.$arreglo["cantidad"].'");
                
                });
                 
                 
            
            </script>
             ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que sucede es que si estas en un loop, lo mas probable es que la funcion de js se este reescribiendo en cada iteracion, lo ideal seria sacar la funcion del loop y colocarla por fuera, por ejemplo:

```
<?
foreach($_SESSION["carrito"] as $indice =>$arreglo){
       
        
            $precio[$indice]=$arreglo["precio"];
            $cantidad[$indice]=$arreglo["cantidad"];
             echo'
             <div id="producto" class="producto" method="post">
                <div  class ="imagen"><img src="'.$arreglo["imagen"].'" heigth=70 width=70></div>
                <div class="descripcion">'.$arreglo["producto"].'</div>
                <div class="talla">'.$arreglo["talla"].'</div>
                <div class="cantidad"> 
                <a class="name-cantidad">Cant.:</a>
                    
                    <div class="restar"><a>-</a></div>
                    <label class="cantidad-producto" id="cantidad-producto'.$indice.'"> <a>'.$arreglo["cantidad"].'</a></label>
                    <div class="sumar"><a data-indice="'.$indice.'" data-cantidad="'.$arreglo['cantidad'].'" onclick="sumaProducto()" id="sumar'.$indice.'">+</a></div>
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="precio">
                <label class="name-precio">Precio:</label>
                <a>'.number_format($arreglo["precio"],2).'</a></div>
                
                <div class="eliminar-producto"><a href="Mycar.php?item='.$indice.'">X</a></div>
            </div>'
}
//CERRAMOS EL LOOP
echo '
            <script>
            
                function sumaProducto(){
                    let indiceActual = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-indice"));
                    let cantidadActual = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-cantidad"));
                    alert("click en producto numero: '.$indice.'");
                    console.log("CantidadActual",cantidadActual);
                    let nuevaCantidad = cantidadActual+1;
                    console.log("NuevaCantidad",nuevaCantidad);
                    
                    ///AQUI VA TU PROCESO DE ACTUALIZACION, POR EJEMPLO UN POST CON JQUERY
                    $.post("/agregaproducto",{ indice: indiceActual, nuevaCantidad: nuevaCantidad},function(data){
                        actualiza tu dom o algo mas
                    })
                }
              
                    
                 
                 
            
            </script>
';
```

El problema que veo en tu codigo es que esperas que la actualizacion de PHP se actualice del lado del cliente, y esto no va a suceder, esto pasa porque el JS corre del lado del cliente y PHP del lado del servidor, entonces, aqui lo que tienes que hacer es un request a tu server para actualizar tu variable de sesion

Es decir que esto es incorrecto:

```
         alert("click en producto numero: '.$indice.'");
         console.log("cantidad : '.$arreglo["cantidad"].'");
         
            
         ';
        
        $_SESSION["carrito"][$indice]["cantidad"] =$arreglo["cantidad"]+1;

     echo'console.log("cantidad es: '.$arreglo["cantidad"].'");
        
        });
```

el proceso

```
 $_SESSION["carrito"][$indice]["cantidad"] =$arreglo["cantidad"]+1;
```

se ejecuta en el servidor al momento de que estas echoing el html

en pocas palabras, JS no tiene acceso a las variables de PHP ya que se ejecutan en capas diferentes